# The correct structure for linking objects

Tags: javascript, object

I've just started getting into OOP and was wondering the correct structure for linking objects together.

Say for example I had an object called "Business":

```
function Business(name, sector, capital, employees, type, id) {
  var self = {
    name: name,
    sector: sector,
    capital: capital,
    employees: employees,
    stock: 0,
    type: type,
    id: id,
  };
  self.produce = function() {
    return self.capital * self.employees;
  }
```

Now in the example above using the properties capital and employees the method 'self.produce' produces output. This output I want to store depending upon the sector.

As a result, would I create a seperate "Sector" object? Or alternatively, within my business object, would it inherit the "Sector" object?

I understand inheritance is used to the attributes of similar objects for example a pet would inherit from an Animal. But in my case of "Business" and "Sector" I'm slightly confused.

Comment: what does *"I want to store"* mean specifically?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to use composition, business "has a" sector but a business "is not" a sector. Business would have an attribute sector, this is passed in the constructor so you can pass different sectors to different businesses. So if the output of produce depends on sector, the code would be in sector classes.

Comment: Would you suggest going forward I should just use composition instead? I watched this video which helped clear quite a bit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA

Comment: Yes for this case definitely use composition, however in your sector classes if you have shared functionality between them, then use inheritance there.